# Bind9 use old file format for zones

Tags: dns, bind9

with BIND version 9.8

how can I use the old format zone files?

```
example.com.    IN  NS  ns1.example.com.
```

instead of the new one

```
$ORIGIN example. etc etc
```

thank you so much

Comment: The old format which you have described is still supported, so no need to change it. Are you describing the actual error - if there is one?

Comment: when  copy the files that i had back up it changes them to the new format when i restart the server. thank you for replying.  is there a converstion tool and is there a way ti disable the conversion to new format?